# cron и websocket не видят компоненты Yii2

Tags: yii2, websocket, cron

При обработке данных через WebSocket или CRON-задачу не могу обратится ни к одному компоненту Yii2, выбивает ошибку `Getting unknown property`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дурацкая ошибка с моей стороны.

Просто при обращении из консоли используется не `web.php`, а `console.php`, поэтому компоненты настраивать нужно там.